# PhantomJS does not skip to next page in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*
    import scrapy
    import os
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time


    def get_path():
        path = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join(
                os.path.dirname(
                    os.path.abspath(__file__)),
                os.path.pardir))
        return os.path.join(
            path, 'tool/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs')

    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(get_path())
    browser.get('http://www.chinaccm.com/37/372002list.shtml')
    elem = browser.find_element_by_id('keyword')
    elem.clear()
    time.sleep(1)
    elem.send_keys('针叶浆'.decode('utf-8'))
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//div[@class="search0013"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    print('----------------------{}'.format(browser.current_url))
```

the output is ----------------------http://www.chinaccm.com/37/372002list.shtml

the click seem not to work
but when I use the chromedriver,it works

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*
    import scrapy
    import os
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time


    def get_path():
        path = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join(
                os.path.dirname(
                    os.path.abspath(__file__)),
                os.path.pardir))
        return os.path.join(
            path, 'tool/chromedriver')

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(get_path())
    browser.get('http://www.chinaccm.com/37/372002list.shtml')
    elem = browser.find_element_by_id('keyword')
    elem.clear()
    time.sleep(1)
    elem.send_keys('针叶浆'.decode('utf-8'))
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//div[@class="search0013"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    print('----------------------{}'.format(browser.current_url))
```

The output is
----------------------http://www.chinaccm.com/WebInfoList.aspx?start_date=2016-5-9&end_date=2017-5-9&keyword=%E9%92%88%E5%8F%B6%E6%B5%86&Column=372002

Comment: Try to save the screenshot of phantomjs before you click `driver.save_screenshot('screen_hires.png')`, I once encounter it when different in resolution cause some elements to be hide in some drop down list (since phantomjs default was mobile view). If it is the case, you could use this `driver.set_window_size(1400,1000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your xpath to `'//div[@class="search0013"]/input'`

Chrome and PhantomJS don't always handle things the same way. With `'//div[@class="search0013"]` you're selecting the div element that contains the button which works with Chrome because the click is sent to where the button is. PhantomJS probably is sending the click somewhere else within the div and misses the button.